# Export a csv file to multiple csv files with batch command

Tags: command-line, batch, csv, export

I have a 100 line csv file, with 5 values per line. I am looking for a way to export each line to its own csv file adding a 2 line header to each. I have used the split command seen elsewhere to create multiple files, but have not found a way to append the header. Also, if possible, can one of the variables be pulled to the file name? Thank you.

Example below.

Orig

```
Jack,7,blue,001   
Jane,6,red,002   
Mike,4,orange,003
```

result

```
List001.csv   
first,number,favorite   
Name,age,color   
Jack,7,blue
```

...

```
List002.csv   
first,number,favorite   
Name,age,color   
Jane,6,red
```

This is the file I am using:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set limit=1
set file=userlist.csv
set lineCounter=1
set filenameCounter=101

set name=Usertable
set extension=csv
for %%a in (%file%) do (
    set "name=%%~na"
    set "extension=%%~xa"
)

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    set splitFile=%name%%filenameCounter%%extension%
    if %lineCounter% gtr %limit% (
        set /a filenameCounter=%filenameCounter% + 1
        set lineCounter=1
        echo Created %splitFile%.
    )
    echo %%a>> %splitFile%

    set /a lineCounter=%lineCounter% + 1
)
```

Comment: this would be easier with PowerShell or VBScript

Comment: @Keltari Why? It's trivial in a batch file. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### I am looking for a way to export each line to its own csv file

> adding a 2 line header to each.

Your batch file is over complicated. There is no need to split the file name or use a counter variable.

**Use the following batch file (example.cmd):**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%i in ('type userlist.csv') do (
  echo first,number,favorite>>List%%l.csv
  echo Name,age,color>>List%%l.csv
  echo %%i,%%j,%%k>>List%%l.csv
  )
endlocal
```

**Example usage:**

```
F:\test>type userlist.csv
Jack,7,blue,001
Jane,6,red,002
Mike,4,orange,003

F:\test>example

F:\test>type List001.csv
first,number,favorite
Name,age,color
Jack,7,blue

F:\test>type List002.csv
first,number,favorite
Name,age,color
Jane,6,red

F:\test>type List003.csv
first,number,favorite
Name,age,color
Mike,4,orange

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Comment: Thank you all. I was over thinking the issue and my train of thought got derailed.

Comment: Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).